# criar um novo dataframe tendo referência outro

Tags: python, python-3.x

Possuo um dataframe com (1242 rows × 325 columns) dele faço uma correlação ".corr()" que resulta em (325 rows × 325 columns)

esse código me exibe as 15 menores correlações do menor valor para o maior valor com base no "ABEV3" (15 rows × 1 columns)

```
ppl = 'ABEV3'
papel = corr[ppl]
corr.query('@papel < 0.1')[ppl].sort_values(ascending=True).head(n=15).index.to_frame().rename(columns={0: ppl})

        ABEV3
PATI3   PATI3
ENMT3   ENMT3
RNEW11  RNEW11
CEDO3   CEDO3
RNEW3   RNEW3
BDLL4   BDLL4
CAMB3   CAMB3
ESTR4   ESTR4
CAMB4   CAMB4
SPRI3   SPRI3
DTCY3   DTCY3
MAPT4   MAPT4
BMEB3   BMEB3
ELEK4   ELEK4
LIPR3   LIPR3
```

A minha dificuldade é em listar (15 rows × 326 columns) sendo que cada coluna fosse o correlacionado e na primeira coluna sendo numerado pela quantidade de linhas, um exemplo feito manualmente:

```
ppl = corr.columns # lista/exibe os indexes das colunas

# executando ppl
ppl
Index(['^BVSP', 'AALR3', 'ABCB4', 'ABEV3', 'ADHM3', 'AGRO3', 'ALPA3', 'ALPA4',
       'ALSO3', 'ALUP11',
       ...
       'VLID3', 'VULC3', 'VVAR3', 'WEGE3', 'WHRL3', 'WHRL4', 'WIZS3', 'WLMM4',
       'WSON33', 'YDUQ3'],
      dtype='object', length=325)

papel = corr[ppl]
corr.query('@papel < 0.1')[ppl].sort_values(ascending=True).head(n=15).index.to_frame().rename(columns={0: ppl})

# quero que o resultado saia com essa estrutura
    ABEV3   PATI3   ITUB4
1   PATI3   MRSA3B  REDE3
2   ENMT3   FLRY3   ESTR4
3   RNEW11  MGLU3   CAMB3
4   CEDO3   SPRI3   DTCY3
5   RNEW3   TUPY3   ENMT3
6   BDLL4   CRPG6   CEDO3
7   CAMB3   USIM3   NORD3
8   ESTR4   TASA4   ELEK4
9   CAMB4   CAMB4   CAMB4
10  SPRI3   LLIS3   CTNM3
11  DTCY3   GEPA4   BMEB3
12  MAPT4   SLED3   MAPT4
13  BMEB3   CPLE6   PATI3
14  ELEK4   PTNT4   SPRI3
15  LIPR3   INEP4   PATI4
```

Não consigo encaixar essa linha dentro de um FOR, ou algum meio que me possa retornar como o exemplo que citei, tenho poucos meses que venho aprendendo, minha estrutura de repetição é muito vaga.